# SQL For xml path on int columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, for-xml-path

Can I use FOR XML PATH in sql for int columns ?
So that I could use it for something like:

```
declare @contactIds = (select id from contacts)
```

and then use it like this:

```
select * from calls where contactId in (@contactIds)
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: You mean you want to store a collection of IDs in a variable, so you can use that later on in the WHERE clause of a query? You can do that with a temporary table.

Comment: if `@contactIds` is a string (which it will be if you use `FOR XML PATH`, then SQL will not inspect the contents of that string, find commas, and then decide to treat that *single* string as if it was in fact several *separate* parameters to `IN()`. I don't know of any language that would do this, so I'm always surprised when people try to do it with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select @contactIds = stuff((select ','+cast(id as varchar(8000))
                            from contacts
                            for xml path('')
                           ), 1, 1, '');
```

You can also use a subquery directly or a table variable:

```
select *
from calls
where contactId in (select id from contacts);
```

My guess is that your problem is more complex than the question, so this doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: I have a query to bring contact name and the number of his outgoing calls and number of incoming calls. So I use subqueries but it takes 12 seconds to run, so I am looking how to improve it...

Comment: There might be ways to actually improve the query.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question with information about what you are actually doing.  You cannot use `@ContactIds` in an `in` statement (well, you can, it just doesn't do what you want).