# For xml - similar function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4, for-xml

the 'for xml' command does not work on pgadmin. Any ideas? I'm trying to get the following query to work from another stackoverflow question: [SQL For xml path on int columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22147235/sql-for-xml-path-on-int-columns)

select @contactIds = stuff((select ','+cast(id as varchar(8000))
                            from contacts
                            for xml path('')
                           ), 1, 1, '');

Comment: "does not work" is not a problem description. [Edit] your post to quote the precise error in full. Anyway, you're copying code from SQL Server to PostGreSQL; that should not be expected to work as is.

Comment: Thank you. Are you aware of a similar function in postgresql? I am new to SQL and I only have access to pgadmin at work.

Comment: Please start by explaining *what* you're trying to do, not just *how* you're currently trying to do it. To join some numbers into a comma-separated string, right? Then I'm sure we can find a dupe if we search.